# Is it possible to add non html comment in underscore.js or lodash templates?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

Is it possible to add non html comments in underscore.js or lodash ?

Something like :

```
<%-- We do this here because... %>
```

So that the comment is not in the resulting generated html code ?

If I write :

```
<!-- We do this here because... -->
```

The comment is in the resulting html.

Thank you.

Comment: You mean inside a template? If not, just use JS comments

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It is a client side template, you'll still see the comment, but it won't repeat etc...

```
<%
// comments go here
%>
```

Comment: I guess the "it won't repeat" (if it is say in a list row) is the most important comment here. BTW, wonder if minifiers do remove such comments

Comment: also wonder if template engines are clever enough to mark and not evaluate that Javascript at all since it contains just comments (or at least load it once and have the Javascript engine optimize it out as whitespace)

Comment: Just guessing that most minifiers aren't expecting a `<script type='bleh'>` html template and wouldn't know that it was ok to remove some value inside there, and if it's an inline string within a js script, it's part of the string value, so it wouldn't know to remove it. I think you'd have to use a standard inline HTML comment for that.